# How to reinitialize app after backgrounding

Tags: ios, background-process

```
-(void) closeUpShopBeforeBackgrounding {

    // this listen to the UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification  

    [self beginBackgroundUpdateTask];
        // do some closing stuff
    [self endBackgroundUpdateTask]; }

- (void) beginBackgroundUpdateTask {
    self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask];
    }]; }

- (void) endBackgroundUpdateTask {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: self.backgroundTask];
    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; }
```

This code is working fine for me, but when I foreground the app again, its dead in the water.  Its as if the `viewDidLoad`s are not firing, and nothing is happening.

Is there anything I need to do when the app foregrounds to kick it back into life?

Comment: The `viewDidLoad`s should only be called when the view is *first* loaded. Maybe you're looking for the events in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3857559/1180785 ?

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I actually found - and use - that solution already.  I was just wondering why the processes/threads were all brought to a halt as soon as I started using the endBackgroundTask when UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification is called.

Comment: I figured it out by re-running init() on my business logic class when UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification is called.  I am not confident I understand what's going on behind the scenes, but the app appears to roar back into life when I start all the timers referenced in the init method of my business logic class.