# How can I save an array of another view controller to the file within the app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array in my root view controller that I need to save (using core data) whenever `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called. How can I send a message to an instance of the root view controller within the delegate?

I was thinking about giving the delegate a reference to view controller when it's set as the root, but that feels inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In your RootViewController .h file,

```
+ (RootViewController *) sharedStore;
```

2) In your RootViewController .m file,

```
+ (RootViewController *) sharedStore
{
    static RootViewController *myStore = nil;

    if (!myStore) {
        myStore = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    }
    return myStore;
}
```

3) Go to your AppDelegate.m file and import your RootViewController

```
#import RootViewController.h
```

4) In your AppDelegate.m file, go to the ApplicationDidEnterBackground method and type:

```
[[RootViewController sharedStore] saveChanges];
```

5) Implement the saveChanges method in RootViewController.

Comment: Isnt the store being set to nil every time this method is called?

Comment: It's a static variable, it won't be assigned more than once in the life time of the object

Comment: So is that line just ignored whenever it is reached and its not the first time?

Comment: @ByronS This is a way to make singleton classes. It will work for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Really bad practices in here: Making a `UIViewController` as singleton and coupling with your `UIApplication`. The cleanest option is to observe for `UIApplication` notifications.

Answer (score 3):

In your root view controller register to receive the ApplicationWillEnterBackground notification. The root view controller can then perform a save when it receives this notification.

Your initial instinct to reduce coupling between controllers was a good one.

Answer (score 0):

AJ112's answer makes:

- A singleton from a `UIViewController`, which is not a good practice.
- Creates coupling with your `UIApplication`, which is something to avoid as much as possible.

There are some `UIApplication` notifications that you can observe from whatever class you need to handle multitasking. Check the answer on this SO question:

[iphone 4 sdk : detect return from background mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857485/iphone-4-sdk-detect-return-from-background-mode)

You can check all the notifications that `UIApplication` posts in here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4